# Unity - Texturing 1 side of a cube using C# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mapping

I have a prefab cube in Unity. I already run some script to position it, and move some of the vertices to change it's shape. Now, I know that to texture it, I have to do something like:

```
 Texture2D myTexture = Resources.Load("sample") as Texture2D;
 cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = (Texture)myTexture;
```

And that works very well. But now, I want to understand how to use UV mapping to assign 2 different texture to my cube (1 for top and 1 for side).

```
 Texture2D topTexture = Resources.Load("topTex") as Texture2D;
 Texture2D sideTexture = Resources.Load("sideTex") as Texture2D;

 //And now, how do I say to only apply to which side?
     cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = (Texture)topTexture;
     cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = (Texture)sideTexture;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Vertices and UVs match up so that each position in the array of Vertices corresponds to the UV vector in the same position.

```
vertices[0] // will map to...
uvs[0]
```

Your vertices describe each of the vertices on your cube. You then essentially pin points of your texture to it. Remember that your texture co-ords are so that they have a min and max value of 0 and 1.

Comment: but how do I use that mapping with the Renderer.material.maintexture command?